# How to combine jQuery-functions with different selectors

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I have a unknown number of different ID's which looks like `#send_1`, `#send_2` and so on. I need to call a jQuery for each of that ID like:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#send_1", function(e){
    var i=1;
    if (something is true) {
        do something
    }    
});
$(document).on("submit", "#send_2", function(e){
    var i=1;
    if (something is true) ) {
        do something
    }    
});
```

So i could write a hundred times the same function just changing `_x` but there shall be a more propper way to solve this.

I usually dont use jQuery so if there is someone who could help me out I really would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my answer had a typo. Try it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attribute [**starts with**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)(^=) selector

```
$(document).on("submit", '[id^="send_"]', function(e){
    var i=1;
    if (something is true) ) {
        do something
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also separate them with a ','

like so:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#send_1, #send_2", function(e){
//...
});
```